# How do I compare the list of a printed outcome to today's date with python?

Tags: python, json

I pulled a list of dates from a website and printed them out. I just can't seem to know how to go through that list of dates and see if any of them match today's date!

Here's my code:

```
import json
from datetime import date
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/") as response:
    source = response.read()

data = json.loads(source)

today = date.today()

for item in data['events']:
    print(item['deadline_time'][0:10])
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
2021-08-13
2021-08-21
2021-08-28
2021-09-11
2021-09-17
2021-09-25
```

My final plan for this project is have python go through the list, and if any date matches today's date, then I want it to send me a text message =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `str` comparison, that requires only one conversion `date > str`

```
today_as_str = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
for item in data['events']:
    if item['deadline_time'][0:10] == today_as_str:
        print("MATCH")
```

---

*For note, you could also parse each string to a datetime, but that is much more costly*

```
today = date.today()
for item in data['events']:
    if datetime.strptime(item['deadline_time'][0:10], "%Y-%m-%d").date() == today:
        print("MATCH")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Azro :)